# More of my Find-the-stars puzzles (Set #2)

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction

**Find-the-stars instructions:**

A Find-the-stars puzzle is played on a square grid that is initially empty except some squares contain arrows.

The goal of the puzzle is to fill some empty squares with stars so that:

1. Every row contains exactly one star.
2. Every column contains exactly one star.
3. Stars are NOT placed in squares that contain an arrow.
4. If a square contains a SOLID arrow,
   THEN exactly one square in the direction of the arrow will contain a star.
5. If a square contains a DASHED arrow,
   THEN none of the squares in the direction of the arrow will contain a star.

[image: 6x6 star puzzle]
[image: 8x8 star puzzle]
[image: 10x10 star puzzle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, nice puzzles. Following the rules leads to a single choice each step. Here are the solutions:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]